# Azure AD Cmdlets and switching directories

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've had my account added to the list of users within a given domain. The user I had created and had added to the directory had a unique *@seurre.com address.

The problem is that when I use the cmdlets associated with the various AD commands they seem to act as if my user account is associated with a seurre.com domain rather than the one I had been invited to.

Dealing with this in the Azure AD portal website is easy enough: the various directories are listed in the popup when I click on my name in the top right hand corner of the window once I'm logged in.

My question however is how do I achieve the same effect from a cmdlet? Does one exist to deal with this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The AzureAD and AzureRM commandlets have a parameter that allows you to specify which tenant/directory you're connecting to.**

Once you've connected to that tenant/directory, you can't switch, you need to reconnect with the other tenantID.

Examples:

```
#Azure AD commandlets
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId contoso.com

#Azure RM Commandlets
Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId contoso.com
```